# How to use base node/class enums?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Maybe it's a really stupid question, but I can't find the answer on Google.

There is a node in Godot - TextEdit. It has several enums. One of them is called MenuItems. One of these is MENU_CLEAR and "= 3" in grey. The description  for it states: "Erases the whole TextEdit text."

My question is: how do I use this info to clear the whole TextEdit text?

I tried simply accessing it with

```
$TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR -> nothing
```

I tried going the long way

```
$TextEdit.MenuItems.MENU_CLEAR -> nothing
```

I tried putting it as a function call

```
$TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR() -> nothing
```

However, if I try to print it, I get it's number

```
print($TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR) -> "3"
```

The description of MENU_CLEAR, at least for me, implies there is a function somewhere there, that should be executed once I make a call to MENU_CLEAR. But I do something wrong. Pls, help

Edit1:
Here's my piece of code (just checking what works, running everything after IF one line at a time):

```
if $TextEdit.get_line_count() > 6:
    $TextEdit.text = ""
    $TextEdit.menu_option($TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR)
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
if $TextEdit.get_line_count() > 6:
    $TextEdit.select(1, 0, 1, 0)    #selects the oldest line
    $TextEdit.menu_option($TextEdit.MENU_CUT)    #deletes it
```

Here's the screenshot of what I get now
[See the slider on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFuxQ.png)
And here's what I want it to be
[Just 6 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6izYr.png)
So there should always be only 6 lines at once on the screen, and the old lines should be deleted. That's where I encountered problems with enums, and that was the reason for the post.
P.S. *Read only* is set to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Clearing TextEdit

I would use `$TextEdit.text = ""` to clear all the text.

---

To address your question. The `MENU_CLEAR` is a constant. It has the value `3`. By itself it does nothing a `3` would not do.

However, `enum` (which are lists of constants with a name) are defined because something uses them. To find out what, I suggest you search for the name of the `enum` (which is `MenuItems` in this case) in the documentation (in particular on the same class).

In this case we find the [`menu_option`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_textedit.html#class-textedit-method-menu-option) method. From the documentation:

> `void menu_option ( int option )`
>
> Triggers a right-click menu action by the specified index. See `MenuItems` for a list of available indexes.

Thus, you would use it like this:

```
$TextEdit.menu_option(TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR)
```

Yes, this also works:

```
$TextEdit.menu_option($TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR)
```

Or you can do it like this (which is the same thing, except it less clear what it means):

```
$TextEdit.menu_option(3)
```

---

### Removing lines from the start of TextEdit

Let us say we want to remove lines at the start. The number of lines we will remove will be `lines_to_remove` (e.g. `1`).

We can do this using `menu_option`. Like this:

1. Select the lines we want to remove. In other words, select form the start of the first line (`0`), to the start of the first line that will stay (`lines_to_remove`):

   ```
   $TextEdit.select(0, 0, lines_to_remove, 0)
   ```
2. <strike>Clear</strike> cut:

   ```
   $TextEdit.menu_option(TextEdit.MENU_CUT)
   ```

   **This will remove the selected text. However, it will also set the clipboard.**

Alternatively, we can manipulate `text`. For example:

```
var lines:Array = $TextEdit.text.split("\n")
var new_text := ""
for index in lines.size() - lines_to_remove:
    if index > 0:
        new_text += "\n"

    new_text += str(lines[index + lines_to_remove])

$TextEdit.text = new_text
```

Here I get the text `$TextEdit.text` and split it by the new line, which gives me an `Array`. Then I concatenate the elements form the `Array` that I want to keep (i.e. skipping the ones I want to remove), And set the result back to `$TextEdit.text`.

---

Regardless of the approach you will find that the cursor will be placed at the start of the text.

So, we are going to store the position before manipulating the text:

```
var cursor_line:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_line()
var cursor_column:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_column()
```

And then set it back... Well, actually we want to subtract the number of lines we removed and then set it back:

```
cursor_line -= lines_to_remove
$TextEdit.cursor_set_line(cursor_line)
$TextEdit.cursor_set_column(cursor_column)
```

*If this resulted in a negative `cursor_line`, it will be placed on the first line. I suppose I could check and set both `cursor_line` and `cursor_column` to zero in that case, but it has not been a problem while trying this out.*

---

### Limiting the number of lines of TextEdit

Now, if you want to make sure you have at most a give number of lines (e.g. six lines). We can read how many lines we have, subtract the maximum you allow, and if the result is positive, that is how many lines have to remove:

```
var target_number_of_lines := 6
var lines_to_remove:int = $TextEdit.get_line_count() - target_number_of_lines
if lines_to_remove > 0:
    pass # rest of the code here
```

Why would you need to do this instead of just removing the first line? Because the user might paste multiple lines at once. Speaking of which, this is intended to run on the `"text_changed"` signal (although it would also work on `_process`):

```
func _on_TextEdit_text_changed() -> void:
    var target_number_of_lines := 6
    var lines_to_remove:int = $TextEdit.get_line_count() - target_number_of_lines
    if lines_to_remove > 0:
        var cursor_line:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_line()
        var cursor_column:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_column()

        $TextEdit.select(0, 0, lines_to_remove, 0)
        $TextEdit.menu_option(TextEdit.MENU_CUT)

        cursor_line -= lines_to_remove
        $TextEdit.cursor_set_line(cursor_line)
        $TextEdit.cursor_set_column(cursor_column)
```

Since this version is cutting the text, it writes the clipboard.

---

Manipulating the `text` property also works (and does not write the clipboard). This is the code:

```
func _on_TextEdit_text_changed() -> void:
    var target_number_of_lines := 6
    var lines_to_remove:int = $TextEdit.get_line_count() - target_number_of_lines
    if lines_to_remove > 0:
        var cursor_line:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_line()
        var cursor_column:int = $TextEdit.cursor_get_column()

        var lines:Array = $TextEdit.text.split("\n")
        var new_text := ""
        for index in lines.size() - lines_to_remove:
            if index > 0:
                new_text += "\n"

            new_text += str(lines[index + lines_to_remove])

        $TextEdit.text = new_text

        cursor_line -= lines_to_remove
        $TextEdit.cursor_set_line(cursor_line)
        $TextEdit.cursor_set_column(cursor_column)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Theraot, I feel I'm a bit stupid now, but I used both options you suggested:      $TextEdit.text = ""  and  $TextEdit.menu_option($TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR)  But they did nothing. I moved this line (with the check on the number of lines) around to the  _process  but it doesn't work anywhere. The new text gets added to the TextEdit box nevertheless. And I somehow can't change the content of any individual line. BUT, if I run the code with breackpoints, this line supposedly gets executed but to no awail.

Comment: @DotFX Testing in Godot 3.4.4 I find that `$TextEdit.menu_option(TextEdit.MENU_CLEAR)` only works when the `readonly` property is set to `false`. But `$TextEdit.text = ""` works regardless. I don't know if there is something else that could be affecting it. I don't know what check of number of lines you are talking about… Anyway, if you want change the content of an individual line try the [`set_line`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_textedit.html#class-textedit-method-set-line) method.

Comment: I updated the post with more info + tried set_line method, it doesn't change anything

Comment: @DotFX I have expanded the answer.

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS, my savior @Thearot, it finally works and deletes the lines! Though, I don't know why, but it works only if I have both the signal function (the last you wrote) and _$TextEdit.select(0, 0, lines_to_remove, 0)_ with _$TextEdit.menu_option(TextEdit.MENU_CUT)_ in the code after line check. If there is only one of them, it still won't work.

Comment: @DotFX I don' know. By the way, I had disregarded the fact that using `MENU_CUT` would write the clipboard. Try using the other version. *I added the version that uses `text` instead, at the end of the answer.*